# Display SQL table content in HTML page using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a SQL table and I would like to display it in a HTML page.
My code is displaying a table but the content is empty although my table is filled with data.

```
    <?php
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $database = 'karin';
        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'karin');
        if (!$connect) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        if (!mysql_select_db($database))
            die("Can't select database");

        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service_messages");
        if (!$results) {
            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
        }


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['partner']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['GUID']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['serviceName']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['serviceID']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['countries']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['rate']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ips']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['callback']?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
```

Why doesn't it show the table content?
Thanks!

Comment: check `echo count($row);`

Comment: `var_dump()` your `$row` to see if there is something in the result

Comment: `mysql_select_db` expect two(2) parameters right ? `mysql_select_db('YourDB', $connection)`

Comment: I don't think $results receives any value for some reason...     $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM service_messages");

Answer (score 2):

1). Don't use **mysql_***. Please use PDO or MySQLi.

2). I don't find any `<table>` (table starting tag) anywhere in your code.

3). Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.

Here's the updated code.

```
    $database = 'karin';
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'karin');
    if (!$connect) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db($database))
        die("Can't select database");

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service_messages");
    if (!$results) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }
     ?>
    <table>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['partner']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['GUID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['serviceName']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['serviceID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['countries']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rate']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ips']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['callback']?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($results)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['partner']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['GUID']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['serviceName']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['serviceID']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['countries']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['rate']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ips']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['callback']?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

For more refrence :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason it works like this:

```
    <?php
    //ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "2014", "cd");

    $q = $mysqli->query("select * from service_messages");

    while($row = $q->fetch_assoc()){
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);



?>
```